# Slack api conversations.history returns error: not_in_channel

Tags: slack-api

I'm starting out with the `Slack API` and trying to just get a list of messages.

Here are my steps:

1. Created a Slack app and gave it `channels:read` and `channels:history`     scope (also `re-installed` it)
2. Queried the list of channels with `conversations.list` (this worked fine)
3. From the output of `conversations.list`, I found a channel that I use and copied the `id`
4. Used the `conversations.history` `api` with the `channelid` from step 3

Result:

```
{ "ok": false, "error": "not_in_channel" }
```

I'm not at all sure what is happening here.   I definitely have messages in the channel, and the [documentation page for that api](https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.history#response) does not say anything about this "not_in_channel" error code.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hello @eric-jorgensen, did you got any solution for adding bot or user to channel by using API. Please let me know. Thank You

Comment: I found the solution, first a bot need to join the channel with [conversations.join](https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.join) and after that a bot can able to send the message to a channel.

Comment: @AbhilashSharma, definitely I spent 3-4 hours to find out same, and then added slack app-permissions, as chat:write.public and it worked.

Comment: It seems like as of now (March 2023) chat:write:public doesn't help

Answer (score 201):

After a long time of investigations (~2 hours), I found an easy approach. For Caleb's answer, I didn't understand how to invite a Bot to the channel. Hence, I am posting this answer.

Go to your Slack Channel and type the following as a message.

```
/invite @BOT_NAME
```

Eg: If your Bot name is `SRE Incident Manager` the command would be as follows.

```
/invite @sre_incident_manager
```

As soon as you start typing `@`, Slack will automatically suggest. So it becomes easy. For this, the Bot needs to be added to your Slack Workspace.

PS: [Original answer](https://meta.discourse.org/t/slack-integration-not-working-not-in-channel-error/140920).

Comment: I added the bot to my channel multiple times using "Reinstall App" button on the app settings page but that didn't help. But then I used ```/invite @BOT_NAME``` and it worked.

Comment: Is there a way to do this through the SDK?

Answer (score 69):

The error `not_in_channel` has the exact meaning, your custom Slack app should be added to the channel.

#### Exact solution 1

To resolve the error, in the Web Slack interface:

- Open `channel settings`
- Click on the `Integrations tab`
- Click `Add apps` and find your custom app.

Slack app might have different interface, see [Iryna Vernik's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64788250/304371).
[image]

---

#### Alternative solution 2

Give access to the bot to all channels by adding workspace wide scope, for example, `chat:write.public`. Depends on your needs and security requirements.

#### Alternative solution 3

To access the channel chat from API specify `Incoming webhook`. Slack will generate a unique URL with the token per each channel. Only convenient for a few channels.

Comment: Thank you. The `chat:write` + `chat:write.public` helped and it was exactly the solution I needed

Comment: @Naoyoshi Aikawa's answer also points out an alternative where you can grant the `conversations.join` scope to your app, and have your code use the `/conversations.join?channel=<id>` API before hitting the `/conversations.list?channel=<id>` API. This keeps a read-only scope, but, like your 2nd alternative, avoids any change to architecture or manual intervention requirement.

Comment: @AlexSorokoletov that also fixed my issue!

Comment: Slack's (minimalist) docs for chat:write.public - https://api.slack.com/scopes/chat:write.public

Answer (score 43):

This error arises when you are using the bot oauth token and the bot is not invited to the channel. To solve this you need to

- Invite the bot(slack app) to join the channel.
- Use the OAuth Access Token instead

To add Bot to your channel you need to write /invite @Bot_name in the slack channel

Comment: does this mean no need to invite if using OAuth Access Token?

Comment: My app was able to post messages to a channel without problems, but kept getting the `not_in_channel` error when it tried adding reactions to those messages. This fixed it.

Answer (score 18):

I also didn't understand how to invite a Bot to the channel. Way that was proposed by Caleb and Keet was not clear for me or not working. From my side, 'invite' work after

- open channel
- in Details tab, choose a 'More'clause
- in dropdown menu, chouse an 'add app'
- in pop-up look for you app (bot)

Also i was use *Bot User OAuth Access Token*, because i need this functionality in private channel (additionaly, you should add for bot *groups:history* scope)

Answer (score 5):

As all others said, you need to join each channel.

The bot can join channel programmatically by using API below:

https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.join

Don't forget to add permission of `conversations.join`

Answer (score 4):

I'm getting started with the Slack API as well, and I've come to realize that `not_in_channel` simply means that the user/bot you are using the token for hasn't *joined* that particular channel you're trying to perform an action on.

**Think of it this way**: if you're using Slack on the web-browser or web-app, you wouldn't be able to post a message on a channel you haven't either joined or was invited to.

☝️ You'll also never run into this issue through the Slack UI/UX because you're not even able to access the channels UNTIL you are invited or join it.

[Click to see png example of a slack message stating my bot being added to a channel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqRLa.png)

However, because we're using the API we can *essentially skip some steps*, and in this case we skipped the step where a user/bot has joined the channel before doing the action we're trying to perform (writing a message, grabbing information, etc).

**How to address this**

There's probably plenty of ways to do it that I'm not versed in, but if you're just concerned about a specific channel or two without the concern of scaling to *x* channels I'll list the way that worked for me.

**/invite Slash Command**

As others have mentioned, putting `/invite` in the message box lets you use Slack's slash command shortcut to add users. What's important is this way also allows us to invite bots to the channel.

Putting "@" triggers Slack to start auto-suggesting, which is why it then becomes easy to find your bot name in the list.

[Click here to see screenshot example of the /invite command with @bot_name_here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Ubln.png)

Hope this helps answer people's question on *why* it's happening, and thank you to the original posts that got me out of my initial mess.

Comment: Thank you! Solved my problem as well, inviting the bot to the channel.

Answer (score 0):

FOr me, instead of invite a user/bot, I invite the app.