# Call slack API conversations.history without inviting into channels

Tags: slack-api

**A little background**

I am developing a read-only python slack script to read the channel history

**Problem**

I run into `not_in_channel` error. I am fully aware of that I can invite the bot to the channel like suggested in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60198159/slack-api-conversations-history-returns-error-not-in-channel).

However, this is my company's workspace and I can't invite a self-developed bot to a channel. All I need is to read the history (read-only) from the script w/o any other action.

PS: I am able to achieve this with legacy token last year.

Comment: Which scopes does your App have in the workspace? You may have to re-install the app with `channels:join` and `channels:history` scopes, join the channel, read the history, and then leave the channel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60198159/slack-api-conversations-history-returns-error-not-in-channel) you linked, you really need an OAuth Token, not a Bot User oauth token